# Looping through huge c# list with inner loops

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a huge list of strings `_wordList List<string>` containing about 100,000 values. The problem I'm having is that I also require multiple nested loops within this. The nested loop is also a list but with a structure containing only variables, containing about 0-100 values depending on what happens

```
    for (int y = 0; y < _wordList.Count; y++)
    {
        string word = _wordList[y];
        for(int x = 0; x < _secondWordList.Count; x++)
        {
            if (!word.Contains(_secondWordList[x].Word) || word == _secondWordList[x].Word)
                continue;

            // do other stuff
        }
    }
```

Here is part of the code, I won't post all of it since most of it will be irrelevant but within the second loop I have about 2 other short loops, the whole function completes in 350-600ms. What would the best way to optimize the loops? The `word.Contains` also have an impact of about 100-150ms on performance.

Comment: Is that a typo? `compareString` looks to be constant in the second (and first, by the way) loop, so you can move the` if` outside your nested loops.

Comment: that was a typo, my bad

Comment: And what do those lists contain? You're obviously not saying the truth about `_wordList`, since you're searching for (at least) words inside those "words", so they're sentences, but are you saying the truth about the second list? Is the second list made of whole words?

Comment: The first list is literally just the english dictionary, the second list can be any combination of a string. For example _wordList[y] can be "hello" and _secondWordList[x] can be "awjoi", so it will continue

Comment: If it was sentences you could have split them into words and checked them against a hash table of original words, but if you have a letter soup, there isn't much you can do. Unless you describe how you use this in more detail (cause right now it sounds useless), you won't get any domain-specific optimizations either.

Comment: `!word.Contains(_secondWordList[x].Word) || word == _secondWordList[x].Word` is strange, perhaps you meant `... && word != ...`. Most likely you could speed that up by swapping the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for a text search, and in this case, you can benefit from projects like [LuceneNet](https://lucenenet.apache.org/).

If the call to string.Contains() didn't exist and you were looking for exact matches I was to suggest that you swap the list for hashset as it'll give you a great performance boost in your case. Like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wordList = new HashSet<string>(); //Assuming Initialized
        var secondWordList = new List<X>(); //Assuming Initialized

        for (var c = 0; c < secondWordList.Count; c++)
        {
            if(wordList.Contains(secondWordList[c].Word))
                continue;

            // do other stuff
        }
    }
```

With this, you're going to iterate on the smaller list and look for the value in the HashSet which has a complexity of O(1), which Means that it'll be extremely fast.